# Windows 10 search is not working properly

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I have various issues with windows search. This is a week old clean install of  windows 10. The related service is running OK.

1. If I type `paint` then there is no result. (worked on win7/8). I have to type `mspaint` to get into paint.
2. If I typed `notep` into search on win7/8 it gave me the notepad app "real-time". In windows 10 there is no result unless I type exactly(!) `notepad` into the search bar. This applies for EVERYTHING. Typing `calcul` won't result in seeing calculator.
3. Typing 'word' returns no result. I had to create a shortcut and click on it to open MS Word. This is very inconvenient.
4. It can't find any software installed.

The best thing in previous windows versions was the search. Just enter start menu or hit winbutton+q and start typing. But now it doesn't work.
I have rebuilt index in Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Advanced several times, but didn't help. Checked the service, it seems to be OK.
Do you have any suggestion to make windows search usable again?

Comment: This problem existed since day 1 or did this happen within that week?  What build of Windows 10 are you using?  Have you attempted to modify or disable Cortana in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found!

Run the below in `PowerShell`:

```
Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | 
Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register 
"$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Solves the issue right away, without any restart.

Comment: *This basically means you removed Cortana at some point.*

Comment: No, didn't touched it.