# Windows 10 Search Bar shows Uninstalled Programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, file-permissions

I have a problem with the Windows 10 search where it keeps showing old programs after I've uninstalled them. One example is Apple Software Update:

[problem.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7OGj.png)

And when I click or right click on it, nothing happens. I want to note that this is not the only program that it keeps showing.

I have uninstalled it, removed it from the start menu, removed it from the registry, removed all Apple folders I could find anywhere yet it's still there.

I've tried rebuilding the search index, I've even deleted the **Windows.edb** file in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows

I've ran **SFC scannow**, **startcomponentcleanup and restorehealth** in **DISM** and they had stuff to repair but now say that everything is fine.

I tried taking ownership of the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data folder, and now I got some weird issues where when I scan for problems in the windows diagnostics, it says incorrect permissions for the windows search directories:

[scanres.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyy0q.png)

And then after I ran it the permissions change in the data-folder to the following:

[perm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKJ6H.png)

No matter what I do I still get "incorrect permissions for the windows search directories" and the problem remains.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe the problem is that these programs still show up regardless of the index, so there might be some Start Menu folder or cache that hasn't cleared - but I wouldn't know what that would be

Comment: This [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1235127/152847) (from a different question) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late, but I had a very similar problem recently that I was able to resolve using [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1290305/1081857)

> Go to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\
>
> Delete the folder \Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy
>
> If you cannot delete the folder, enter into the folder and delete as many as the sub folders as your system permits.

I restarted Cortana from Task Manager, but the original link mentions logging out and back in again which might be worth trying.

This cleared out my old `Visual Studio 2017` and `Powershell 7 (Preview)` search results. It also fixed the issue I was having setting a custom `-WorkingDirectory` path in the Powershell shortcut which would cause Search to hang for 15 seconds and fail to open

Comment: Is there any way to fix this permanently? Your workaround worked for me, (although the folder was called Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy on my system), but now every time I uninstall or install a program and want to update search, I have to delete that folder.

Comment: I found that the deleting the subfolder of  C:\Users\"User"\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_xxxxxx work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had been trying to find a solution for almost a year after countless hours of research, index rebuilds and resets, Windows search troubleshooting, looking through Start Menu items, reinstalling apps, removing shortcuts to no avail. I finally got it resolved by doing as [Tawei mentioned above](https://superuser.com/questions/1489957/windows-10-search-bar-shows-uninstalled-programs/1682171#comment2570054_1553235):

> I found that the deleting the subfolder of C:\Users"User"\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_xxxxxx work for me.

I suggest Microsoft improve the Search and Indexing troubleshooter by automatically removing the "Microsoft.Windows.Search*" directory, it would be helpful for completely resetting the Windows Search feature and resolving these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Search is broken on a few systems for a few months already. Unfortunately I didn't find another workaround than installing classic shell which is using a custom search implementation compared to the Windows 10 1903 default search (it still relies on the windows vista/7 indexer).