# BingSearchEnabled registry setting breaks my non-web search

Tags: windows-10

When I set `BingSearchEnabled = 0` in registry Windows search stops working. When I set `BingSearchEnabled = 1` Windows search works again but includes web search which I do not want.

The setting is found in this registry key

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search
```

These are all the settings found in the registry key

```
CanCortanaBeEnabled            REG_DWORD   0x0
CortanaCapabilities            REG_SZ      PhoneCall,SpeechLanguage
CortanaCapabilityFlags         REG_DWORD   0x2200
CortanaConsent                 REG_DWORD   0x0
CortanaMUID                    REG_SZ      MUID=9f732ec974834c269edf073bc3940476
DeviceHistoryEnabled           REG_DWORD   0x0
HasAboveLockTips               REG_DWORD   0x1
InstalledWin32AppsRevision     REG_SZ      {2BC03488-0C8C-4367-8AC4-73D37CC354B5}
InstalledPackagedAppsRevision  REG_SZ      {A3EDD1F2-C5E4-4CC0-962C-090B859A87C0}
ReplaceCortanaCheckRefreshed   REG_DWORD   0x1
CortanaIsReplaceable           REG_DWORD   0x0
CortanaIsReplaced              REG_DWORD   0x0
CortanaInAmbientMode           REG_DWORD   0x0
CortanaServiceTarget           REG_SZ      cortana.bing.com
CortanaStateLastRun            REG_BINARY  2E0E6A5D00000000
AnyAboveLockAppsActive         REG_DWORD   0x0
IsWindowsHelloActive           REG_DWORD   0x0
IsAssignedAccess               REG_DWORD   0x0
NamespaceSettingsRevision      REG_SZ      {BFB53031-F975-40F4-90DA-1A76781F337D}
BingSearchEnabled              REG_DWORD   0x0
AllowCortana                   REG_DWORD   0x0
AllowSearchToUseLocation       REG_DWORD   0x0
```

I'm running Windows 10 Home version 1903 (OS Build 18362.329) and I have the latest Windows updates according to Windows Update.

Here is a screenshot of what happens when I try to search:
[image: screenshot]
 In the screenshot I first clicked the Start Button and then I typed "event viewer". In the upper left corner of the dark gray area, you'll find a small blue square. There are multiple of these, animated as if Windows was actually searching. I've obviously tried waiting to see if it would finish.

I've also tried asking Windows to rebuild the search index.

How do I make Windows search work without having web search enabled?

**Update #1**

Also worth noting that when `BingSearchEnabled = 0` the process `SearchUI.exe` is constantly running at about 32% CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I set BingSearchEnabled = 0 in registry Windows search stops working. When I set BingSearchEnabled = 1 Windows search works again but includes web search which I do not want.  It's also worth noting that when BingSearchEnabled = 0 the process SearchUI.exe is constantly running at about 32% CPU.

This is a known issue with **[KB4512941](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512941/windows-10-update-kb4512941)**.

> Windows Desktop Search may not return any results and may have high CPU usage
>   Microsoft is getting reports that a small number of users may not receive results when using Windows Desktop Search and may see high CPU usage from SearchUI.exe when searching after installing KB4512941. This issue is only encountered on devices in which searching the web from Windows Desktop Search has been disabled.

Microsoft plans to patch this problem in September 2019.

> We are working on a resolution and estimate a solution will be available in mid-September.

Source: [Windows 10, version 1903 and Windows Server, version 1903](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#676msgdesc)

> How do I make Windows search work without having web search enabled?

If you don't feel like waiting, for a fix to be released, I would revert back to KB4512508 (18362.295) by uninstalling KB4512941 (18362.329).  **In the end, the actions you have taken should have disabled the web searches and allowed local searches to work, without causing high CPU issues with SearchUI.exe.**

Answer (score 3):

The problem is linked to update KB4512941.

Microsoft say they will repair it mid-September.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512941/windows-10-update-kb4512941