# Overheating PC after 40% CPU/RAM usage

Tags: overheating

My PC with an intel Core (TM) i-7 with four cores and a 16 Go RAM starts heating up when reaching 40% of CPU's usage and/or 40% RAM usage.
Is there a way to solve this matter ?

Comment: What do you want to solve? Computers produce more heat as they get busier. The fans kick in to cool it. If the airflow isn't clear or the fans are not working properly it will fail to cool itself adequately. Without knowing what temperatures it's reaching, that's all anyone can say.

Comment: It reaches 65-85 °C, sometimes even 90° or a bit more.

Comment: Did you install the latest cumulative update ? Then you probably should read this to fix the issue - [How to Fix High CPU Usage After Windows 10 KB4512941 Update](https://beebom.com/fix-high-cpu-usage-windows-10-kb4512941-update/).

Comment: Please update your question to indicate what CPU you have specifically.  An "Intel Core i-7" is not descriptive enough.  It would also help if you indicate the reason you believe the CPU is overheating.  You should also indicate what version of Windows 10 you have, we need to know which cumulative updates you have installed, there is a known issue with the most recent cumulative update for Windows 10 version 1903.  Without this information, a helpful quality answer, cannot be submitted.  [Did you disable Bing search by chance?](https://superuser.com/questions/1479360/)

Comment: Please name your Socket and the type of CPU you have plugged in it. Sometimes the cooler wasn't precisely mounted or the thermal paste wasn't put on all of the die. The temperatures you have been experiencing _are definitely too high_ for a proper system.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanup your fans, and air vents obstructed by dust. Use a brush to help.

If this is a desktop, open the case, make sure that your fan is correctly locked on the CPU; if not, the thermal paste is probably damaged, you'll need to clean the old thermal paste on the CPU and on the fan and apply a small drop of new paste before locking the CPU again. Some fans for desktop CPUs have a poor locking mechanism in plastic which can be unlocked because of some shocks or torsions while moving the PC.

If this is a notebook, use it on a flat table, not on your bed as it obstructs the air vents below; cleaning the fans is not so easy, you need more precise tools to open it; you may need assistance from a professional "clinic" that knows how to check the correct mounting.

Also check your BIOS settings and lock for "silence mode": in summer when the temperature is over 25°C, this mode does not work properly, you may want to change it back to normal mode even if it causes some noise.

Look at the hardware monitor: make sure the fans have a suitable rotating speed detected (not 0): check that the fan cables are connected (especially the fan attached directly on the CPU).

In summer, you may also want to disable "optimized" settings for performance and restore the normal settings, which also include CPU features like SpeedStep/EIST being enabled, and default CPU and RAM frequencies (the detailed settings is specific to each brand/model, their name in BIOS settings vary a lot, I can't be more precise, but usually the "restore default" option in BIOS should be your friend, the only settings that you may need to tune again is for UEFI/legacy boot mode, and boot drive order if you have several storage volumes; almost everything else is for "overclockers" that have a new hardware and want to boost it, for modest gain, and have a dustfree environment).

Also if you're a smoker, learn to avoid that near your PC: it obstructs the fans, and this obstruction is very hard to remove as dust will be "glued" in it and really hard to remove correctly even with a brush.

Make sure also your PC is not directly on the ground, especially if you have a pet. Don't let your cat install on the PC: it will leave thin hair constantly obstructing the fans and airvents. Don't place the PC below your desktop near the wall, keep free space around it, use a small support to keep it away from dust on the ground. You may also find accumulation of thin threads from spider webs. This happens even if you maintain your room clean, you should be more careful and use better equipment. Some rural places have lot of spiders coming from outdoor.

In general you should physically cleanup your PC vents and fans every 1-2 months: inspect it regularly to see how fast it accumulates dust. The same applies to other electronic equipments, like modern TVs which are also real PCs with heating problems and internal CPUs. You can know that your PC requires cleanup if you see dust along its cables. Take the time to clean it completely and not superficially and to cleanup the working space as well.